# Play decoded audio buffer with AudioWorklet

Tags: javascript, service-worker, audio-streaming, web-audio-api, audio-worklet

I want to play the `AudioBuffer` that I have gotten from `AudioContext.decodeAudioData()` with `AudioWorklet`. I'm currently able to play decoded audio buffer with `AudioBufferSourceNode` but as you know this method will execute the task on the main thread which is not what I want, the thing I want is to play audio in the background which seems it's only possible to do with workers. but workers can't access the [Web Audio Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API). so the only way is `AudioWorklet`

setup worklet :

```
var audioContext = new AudioContext()
await audioContext.audioWorklet.addModule("./playing-audio-processor.js");
PlayingAudioProcessor= new AudioWorkletNode(
    audioContext,
    "playing-audio-processor"
);
PlayingAudioProcessor.connect(audioContext.destination);
audioContext.resume();
```

decoding and sending it to the worklet (I'm sure that the passed `audioBuffer` does not have any problem and can be easily played with `AudioBufferSourceNode`)

```
let ctx = new AudioContext();
ctx.decodeAudioData(new Uint8Array(audioData).buffer, (audioBuffer) => {
    //set `audioData` of worklet to a float32array
    myAudioWorklet.port.postMessage(audioBuffer.getChannelData(0))
})
```

the length of passed audio data array (`audioBuffer.getChannelData(0)`) is `960` which is greater than the length of `outputs[0][0]` so I splitted it (actully it doesn't seem to be a good idea and I think this is why I have not expected audio output)

```
class PlayingAudioProcessor extends AudioWorkletProcessor {
    audioData = []
    constructor() {
        super();
        //set listener to receive audio data
        this.port.onmessage = (data) => {
            this.audioData = data.data
        }
    }

    process(inputs, outputs, parameters) {
        //playing each 128 floats of 960 floats
        for (let i = 0; i < this.audioData.length / 128; i++) {
                for (let b = 0; b < 128; b++) {
                    if ((i * 128) + b <= this.audioData.length) {
                        outputs[0][0][b] = this.audioData[(i * 128) + b];
                    }
                }
            }
        return true;
    }

}

registerProcessor("playing-audio-processor", PlayingAudioProcessor);
```

the problem is now that the audio result is nothing but a meaningless noisy sound that depends on the loudness of the input data.

I really need to solve this, please put anything that might be helpful for me.
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're writing all the samples within a single `process()` call. You would instead need to write only 128 samples per `process()` call to achieve the desired result.

The first invocation would need to write sample 1 to 128 out of your `AudioBuffer`, the second invocation would need to write sample 129 to 256, and so on...

Comment: that's great!, thank you very much. now there is only one problem which I can't understand why it's happening. it seems some frames (a little but sensible) at the end of each data has cut and the end of a second of voice is not smooth but very sudden

Comment: It's hard to say. Maybe these samples get already swallowed by `decodeAudioData()`. It has a lot of quirks which don't really get fixed anymore since it is meant to be replaced by Web Codecs one day.

Answer (score 1):

`AudioBufferSourceNode` doesn't play audio on the main thread. None of the `AudioNode` objects do that (except for `ScriptProcessorNode`, which is deprecated). All audio processing and playback for the Web Audio API is performed inside a separate web audio thread. Only the parts of the audio nodes that send control messages run on the main thread. By which I mean that a brief message gets sent between threads when you call a method like `start()` or `setValueAtTime()`, etc.

https://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#control-thread-and-rendering-thread